# Issue in reading lines of file

Tags: perl

Suppose I'm reading each line of the following data:

```
40556;20/02/2001;;MG;M^12/08/67^F^16/03/89^SP^14/02/61
;;;;;M1|F1|SP1;12;11;11;7;7;12;54.340;CSF1PO
;;;;;M1|F1|SP1;8;6;6;8;8;8;2.036;TPOX
;;;;;M1|F1|SP1;8;9.3;9.3;9;9;9.3;3.077;TH01
;;;;;F1|SP1;;;7;9.3;9.3;9.3;2.419;TH01
;;;;;F1|SP1;;;16;18;18;17;1.361;vWA
;;;;;F1|SP1;;;9;16;16;15;1.366;D18S51
40555;20/02/2001;;MG;F^23/06/2000^SP^01/09/64
;;;;;F1|SP1;;;11;13;12;12;Exclusão;D16S539
;;;;;F1|SP1;;;12;8;9;9;Exclusão;D7S820
;;;;;F1|SP1;;;14;10;9;9;Exclusão;D13S317
;;;;;M1|F1|SP1;13;14;14;14;14;12;-;D16S539
;;;;;M1|F1|SP1;10;8;8;9;8;11;Exclusão;D7S820
;;;;;M1|F1|SP1;12;12;12;8;11;11;Exclusão;D13S317
```

I split the lines as following:

```
my @fields = split /;/;
```

Notice that, in the lines beginning with empty space ($fields[0] eq ""), I have a kind of pattern (M1|F1|SP1 or F1|SP1), then it changes to the other kind in the lines below.

I'd like to skip the lines when the pattern changes, compared to the first line. I'm reading this data inside a loop. So it would be nice to start the loop again once it gets to the different pattern, or maybe go to the next line beginning with a number.
How can I do that?

Comment: Please include your current code.

Comment: I assume you mean that you want them grouped according to the value of that column.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, you need something like this:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use constant { SKIP=>1, READ=>2 };
my ($skip, $pattern) = (SKIP, "");
while (<DATA>) { chomp;
    my @v = split(/;/);
    if ($skip == SKIP and $v[0] =~ /\d+/) { 
        $pattern=""; $skip = READ;
    } elsif ($skip == READ) {
        $pattern = "$v[5]" if not $pattern;
        if ($pattern eq $v[5] ) { 
            print( join(",", @v), "\n");
        } else { $skip = SKIP; }
    }
}

__DATA__
40556;20/02/2001;;MG;M^12/08/67^F^16/03/89^SP^14/02/61
;;;;;M1|F1|SP1;12;11;11;7;7;12;54.340;CSF1PO
;;;;;M1|F1|SP1;8;6;6;8;8;8;2.036;TPOX
;;;;;M1|F1|SP1;8;9.3;9.3;9;9;9.3;3.077;TH01
;;;;;F1|SP1;;;7;9.3;9.3;9.3;2.419;TH01
;;;;;F1|SP1;;;16;18;18;17;1.361;vWA
;;;;;F1|SP1;;;9;16;16;15;1.366;D18S51
40555;20/02/2001;;MG;F^23/06/2000^SP^01/09/64
;;;;;F1|SP1;;;11;13;12;12;Exclusão;D16S539
;;;;;F1|SP1;;;12;8;9;9;Exclusão;D7S820
;;;;;F1|SP1;;;14;10;9;9;Exclusão;D13S317
;;;;;M1|F1|SP1;13;14;14;14;14;12;-;D16S539
;;;;;M1|F1|SP1;10;8;8;9;8;11;Exclusão;D7S820
;;;;;M1|F1|SP1;12;12;12;8;11;11;Exclusão;D13S317
```